# How (else) can I make an SVG clickable for linking?

Tags: html, hyperlink, svg

I'm using object to embed some SVGs that I would like to href to other pages.

**First option** is to change the xml inside
See Inkscape FAQ-s 1.8.1
http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions

But I want to use javascript to dynamically change the url if they have js enabled. AND i want to reuse the same SVG doc anyway but with different links. So I need another option.

**Second option**, wrap the embedded object in a 'a href' tag, but that doesn't seem to work, it makes the div part that ISN'T covered by SVG a clickable link but not the svg.

{Further complicated  because inside the object I have a .png (made clickable by using usemap) which if the browser falls back to I get TWO clickable areas. The PNG and DIV remainder....}

**Third Option**, a USEMAP for the svg itself! No that doesn't seem to work either.

Are there any other options? Javascript answers welcome, for reference purposes, but ideally not.

EDIT to add HTML code

```
<object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="svgimage.svg" >
    <img src="pngbackupforIEpre9androidpre3.png" type="image/png" usemap="#mapping"/>
</object>
</a>
<map name="mapping">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="svgfreezone.php" />
</map>
```

EDIT to add SVG XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 617.875 320.75" width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<metadata>
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
<dc:title/>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(-66.78125,-339.125)">
<rect style="stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-width:3.5999999;fill:#ff0000;" height="317" width="614" y="341" x="68.6"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Notes; The svg has been vacumed def'd, saved as plain and then optimised using "Simplify colours Y, Style to xml N, Group Collapsing    Y, Enable ID stripping  Y, Embed rasters N, Keep editor data N, Enable viewboxing Y, Strip xml prolog    N, Set precision 3, Indent None."

Comment: Do you have a link to the code you currently have, or can you post it in the question.  Both the HTML and the SVG you're trying to embed.

Comment: Sure I-ll add the html... but why do you need the xml for the svg?

Comment: You said the link was in the SVG?  SVG handles its own click events so if you're clicking on an SVG then that code is relevant.

Comment: @robertc, sorry I wasn't clear, the first option for svg is indeed to put it in the xml .svg code but I can't because I want to reuse the img.svg for different links. So in this case the svg's xml is not a factor.

Comment: If you're embedding an SVG then it is a factor, because click events and scripting still happen within the SVG, that's why wrapping it in an `a` or adding a `usemap` doesn't work - it's not a static image.  That's why I keep asking to see the SVG code.

Comment: @robertc, oh I didn't know that. The svg has about 130,000 characters, SO allows me to post 30,000. Shall I post a certain section? Or if it is easier the svg image is currently being left for browser testing at  www.gamemorize.com

Comment: OK :) Can you link to it, or post a simpler SVG which has the same results?

Comment: @robertc, thanks for your patience! I've put up a simple svg with notes on optimisation settings. The link is the index page of [link](http://www.gamemorize.com), on the page if you wish you will see the original svg and the simple svg (one is compressed, svgz).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see two options:

**First option:** (This will be only good if this is a web app; if its a "regular" website this may not be suitable for you)
Use a regular **href** in the SVG, which links to an anchor. That is - a #something url. Just a hash. 
Now use a "special" hash which you can recognize, and then hook to the window's "hashchange" event, and see if the hash == '#my_special_hash' - then redirect to wherever you like.

**Second option:**
Put a placeholder href in the SVG, and read the SVG content with JavaScript.
Then replace the href with the url you really want, and inject it to the page.
Most browsers support SVG as a source image, and as an object.
You can see how the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library builds SVG if you need actual code. Note that it uses VML for fallback because of lack of support in some old browsers.

Good luck! :-)

Comment: How do you differ a web app and a website? Do you have any links to this # features, I'm a pretty new to svg and i can't really follow your first option, sorry. I'm also going to reaserch the possibility of accessing the svg's xml with javascript.... thanks for the ideas!

Comment: I do not think it's anything official, it's probably my own personal way to define it.
But I think of a web app as something (web based) which is not just HTML and graphics, but uses more actual code in its client side. And it means that your pages are event driven, and they usually use javascript to access network.
Facebook by my definition is a web app, so is Google+. So is Stackoverflow in many parts.

Comment: The first option is not about SVG; SVG allows you to put HREFs, so you just need to do something like <... href="#special_link">

Comment: And then on your HTML page, you can register the "hashchange" event. If you are not familiar with javascript and do not use any JS framework, you can do something like:
    <body onhashchange="if (window.location.hash='#special_link') window.location='http://www.google.com'; ">

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-image` css property on the anchor to the svg image and it will be clickable.

I used one in [this page](http://wholcomb.github.io/SimpleSignaling/).

```
#infoButton {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('info.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to always put `display: block;` when using SVG some browsers don't support SVG properly.